# Genre, and similar music to the "Powerful Infant" from Super Mario

Tags: instrumental, similar-artists

I am looking for artists similar in sound with the "Powerful Infant" track from Super Mario computer game.

I also remeber I've heard similar music in some movie which had more african/jungle vibes and monkey sounds mixed in.

Comment: As @guidot says, the question as written is off-topic; however, if you recast it just as a [tag:similar-artists] question, you might be okay.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the rhythm section is playing a [bossa-nova clave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_(rhythm)#Bossa_nova_pattern), so that genre might have what you're looking for.